# JSON parse always results in NaN for first value

Tags: json

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2DTX8/3/)

i have my JSON code and when i try to parse it the first ID is always 0 and i cant figure out why.

iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myFirstJSON.length; i++) {
    var dayEvent = dayEvent + myFirstJSON[i].ID + '   ';
}
```

result:

NaN 491 489 482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NaN comes from `var dayEvent = dayEvent + myFirstJSON[i].ID + '   ';` where you use `dayEvent` before you initialize it (undefined + a number gives you NAN). If you initialize it, the NaN goes away

```
var dayEvent = '';
for (var i = 0; i < myFirstJSON.length; i++) {
    dayEvent = dayEvent + myFirstJSON[i].ID + '   ';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DTX8/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define initial value of `dayEvent` before start using it:

```
var dayEvent = "";
for (var i = 0; i < myFirstJSON.length; i++) {
    dayEvent = dayEvent + myFirstJSON[i].ID + '   ';
}

document.writeln(dayEvent);
```